# How to merge all rows for same id as different column

Tags: sql, select, group-by, pivot, netezza

I have a table such the customers have unique id but they have different date information for each account type. But I want to get all date information for each customer together on the same row, and also I want to show date for each type as different column.

```
id        date        type
--       ------      -----
1        2014/10/25    a
2        2014/08/02    a
1        2014/10/07    b
```

But I want to get this table as

```
id       type_a      type_b
--       ------      ------
1        2014/10/25  2014/10/07
2        2014/08/02
```

So how should I write my select statement for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'a' THEN a.date ELSE '' END) type_a, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'b' THEN a.date ELSE '' END) type_b
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: your query needs to be dynamic,it will give the result for two types only, suppose there are multiple types on same id and also type may vary from different id to id, then how you gonna to create new columns

Answer (score -1):

Check This one.....

```
select  id,convert(varchar(max),a ,111) as type_a,isnull(convert(varchar(max),b ,111),'') 

as type_b from tableName pivot (max(date1) for type1 in (a,b)) As pvt
```

same thing you can do with Dynamic Pivoting

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(type1)
                      FROM tableName 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
                        print @cols

SELECT @query =

'SELECT  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
   t.id,
   t.date1,
  t.type1
  FROM tableName AS t

) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(date1) 
  FOR type1 IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p ; ' ;  

  execute(@query);
```

Comment: The question has the Netezza tag, so was assuming this was for Netezza.  If so, then PIVOT and SQL Server procedural stuff won't work.